# Inno Setup driver installation APIs

Tags: windows, driver, inno-setup

I'm having trouble calling a couple Windows APIs to install drivers. Specifically:
[SetupCopyOEMInf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [DriverPackageInstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The prototypes I've used don't appear to be working, perhaps due to Unicode strings or use of pointers. Note: I'm using the Unicode build of Inno Setup. Some of the parameters may be NULL, but I don't know how to specify NULL in the Code section.

Here are the prototypes I tried:

```
function SetupCopyOEMInf(SourceInfFileName: String;
  OEMSourceMediaLocation: String; OEMSourceMediaType: Longword;
  CopyStyle: Longword; DestinationInfFileName: String;
  DestinationInfFileNameSize: Longword; var RequiredSize: Longword;
  DestinationInfFileNameComponent: String): Longword;
external 'SetupCopyOEMInfW@setupapi.dll stdcall setuponly';

function GetLastError(): Longword;
external 'GetLastError@kernel32.dll stdcall setuponly';

type
InstallerInfo = record
  pApplicationId: String;
  pDisplayName: String;
  pProductName: String;
  pMfgName: String;
end;

function DriverPackageInstall(DriverPackageInfPath: String;
  Flags: Longword; pInstallerInfo: InstallerInfo;
  var pNeedReboot: Longword): Longword;
external 'DriverPackageInstall@files:difxapi.dll stdcall setuponly';
```

The prototypes may be correct and I'm encountering a different error, I don't know. I know something is wrong because the calls fail (return fail code) and making the same calls from a C program works fine.

**UPDATE 1:**
`DriverPackageInstall` may not be immediately useful. The DLL must be registered before being used. Not saying it isn't possible, just requires more work than appropriate for this question.

**UPDATE 2, 3:**
Example usage:

```
const
  MAX_PATH = 260;
  SPOST_PATH = 1;
  SP_COPY_DELETESOURCE = $0000001;

procedure InstallUsbDriver();
var
  RequiredSize: DWORD;
  DestinationInfFileName: String;
  DestinationInfFileNameComponent: String;
begin
  SetLength(DestinationInfFileName, MAX_PATH);
  SetLength(DestinationInfFileNameComponent, MAX_PATH);
  if not SetupCopyOEMInf(ExpandConstant('{app}\driver.inf'),
    ExpandConstant('{app}'), SPOST_PATH, SP_COPY_DELETESOURCE,
    DestinationInfFileName, MAX_PATH, RequiredSize,
    DestinationInfFileNameComponent) then begin
    MsgBox('Error installing USB driver: ' + SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError),
      mbError, MB_OK);
    CancelWithoutPrompt := True;
    WizardForm.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You must allocate space for the `DestinationInfFileName` string parameter at least to the `MAX_PATH` length (via `SetLength` procedure) before you pass it to the function.

Comment: I'm not expecting it to be used since I specify a size of 0 for it.

Comment: The problem is that you're passing the buffer (which cannot be NULL unless you'd use the only available pointer type, the `PAnsiChar`). There is a note in the reference: *"If DestinationInfFileName is specified and this buffer size is less than the size required to return the destination .inf filename (including full path), this function fails."* and you have it specified and its size is less than the required size. I'll include to my post also a version which will use the real pointer to char type, `PAnsiChar`. This will require to use ANSI version of the function though. I'll be right back..

Comment: No luck. I set both 'var strings' to max length and it still fails.

Comment: Just a silly question. Is that file already installed ? I mean, are you performing the `InstallUsbDriver` procedure after installation stage when the `driver.inf` file is in the application folder ? What is the error you're getting ?

Comment: Yes the file is installed (I can see it in the directory when the error msgbox pops up). I'm calling `InstallUsbDriver` in a `AfterInstall` on the INF (after the CAT file). I wish I had more information why it fails. `GetLastError` only returns 0.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26193/discussion-between-tlama-and-ioan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it took me time to figure out why the given and validated answer doesn't work, I post here the correct answer for my case. I am using InnoSetup 5.5.3 in ANSI mode. When declaring external method with var modifier for strings, I have an access violation error. You should just not add this modifier.

Easy copy/paste answer:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

function GetLastError: DWORD;
  external 'GetLastError@kernel32.dll stdcall setuponly';

function SetupCopyOEMInf(SourceInfFileName, OEMSourceMediaLocation: String;
  OEMSourceMediaType, CopyStyle: DWORD; DestinationInfFileName: String;
  DestinationInfFileNameSize: DWORD; var RequiredSize: DWORD;
  DestinationInfFileNameComponent: String): BOOL;
  external 'SetupCopyOEMInf{#AW}@setupapi.dll stdcall setuponly';

const
  MAX_PATH = 260;

  SPOST_NONE = 0;
  SPOST_PATH = 1;
  SPOST_URL = 2;

  SP_COPY_DELETESOURCE = $0000001;
  SP_COPY_REPLACEONLY = $0000002;
  SP_COPY_NOOVERWRITE = $0000008;
  SP_COPY_OEMINF_CATALOG_ONLY = $0040000;

function InstallDriver(PathLocation, FileName : String) : Boolean;
var
  RequiredSize: DWORD;
  DestinationInfFileName: String;
  DestinationInfFileNameComponent: String;
begin
  Result := False;
  if FileExists(PathLocation+'\'+FileName) then begin
    SetLength(DestinationInfFileName, MAX_PATH);
    SetLength(DestinationInfFileNameComponent, MAX_PATH);
    Result := SetupCopyOEMInf(PathLocation+'\'+FileName,
                              PathLocation, SPOST_PATH, SP_COPY_DELETESOURCE,
                              DestinationInfFileName, MAX_PATH, RequiredSize,
                              DestinationInfFileNameComponent);
  end;
end;
```

Use it like this:

```
 if not InstallDriver(ExpandConstant('{app}\drivers'), 'mydriver.inf') then
 begin
  MsgBox('Error: '+SysErrorMessage(GetLastError), mbError, MB_OK);
 end
```

Comment: Do you know why there is the `#ifdef UNICODE` ? Let me explain. A code written with such conditional is supposed to run on both versions of Inno Setup, ANSI even Unicode. So, either it's usage or the note that you're using ANSI version of Inno Setup is pointless. Which is that ? Besides, if the code from my answer didn't work, it should not be accepted in the first place. I don't like people who just copy some code without knowing what it even does claiming just *"my version works, the other one doesn't"*. Programming isn't trial failure science!

Comment: @TLama It might be my fault for reassigning the answer. I wish you had left your answer in place as it provided other information. The only thing I can remember that was different was the declaration of `SetupCopyOEMInf`. I think you & I solved some issues in chat, which is unavailable. I checked my own working code and found it to match this answer, as opposed to yours. As you mention, the UNICODE condition is important. Your answer and guidance certainly led me to my solution, it simply may not have been updated afterwards.

Comment: @Ioan, yup, that's possible. But I keep it deleted since it doesn't add anything to this post. It was just a literal translation of the used prototypes from MSDN.

Comment: @TLama If the poster doesn't update their answer, I don't see why you couldn't leave yours up and correct it to answer the issues brought up here (regarding Unicode and error with var on strings). It would be a better and more useful answer, in my opinion.